# How to prove this with Einstein summation index notation?

Tags: notation

Show that

$$\nabla \left ( \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{r} \right ) = \mathbf{u} + \nabla \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{r}$$

where **u** is any vector field and **r** is the position vector.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $i$th component of the left-hand side is$$\partial_i(u_jr_j)=u_j\delta_{ij}+(\partial_iu_j)r_j=u_i+(\partial_iu_j)r_j.$$In this final expression, the first (second) term is the $i$th component of $\vec{u}$ ($\nabla\vec{u}\cdot\vec{r}$).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

The  $j^{\text{th}} $ component will be

$$\frac{\partial u_ir_i}{\partial x_j}=$$

$$u_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} + x_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} =$$